# Dynamic SQL Select statement having into keyword

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which creates tables and inserts into that tables dynamically, here everything going fine. The problem with the below code

```
execute immediate
'SELECT NAME 
INTO variable1
FROM table1 
WHERE ID = 2';
```

The error is:
missing keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
execute immediate
  'SELECT NAME FROM table1 WHERE ID = 2'
  into variable1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the `INTO` to be part of the dynamic SQL statement.  It needs to be part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id = 2'
  INTO variable1;
```

You almost certainly want to be using bind variables in your dynamic SQL statement to reduce the overhead of constantly hard-parsing the statement.  The number 2 is almost certainly coming from somewhere else and is not supposed to be hard-coded.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id = :val'
  INTO variable1
 USING some_variable_with_a_value_of_2;
```